# How do I limit an input's value with javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I need an input value to be limited to [1, 5000000]. I want to do it programmatically. I am using AngularJS for my web application. Here is the code I wrote:

html

```
<input ng-change="checkLimit()" type="number" min="1" max="5000000" name="input" ng-model="data.flips" required/>
```

js

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.checkLimit = function() {
        $scope.data.flips = $scope.data.flips > 5000000 ? 5000000 : 
        $scope.data.flips;
        $scope.data.flips = $scope.data.flips < 1 ? 1 : $scope.data.flips;
    }
});
```

I know for sure that the function runs, but the value in the input field and the variable is not updated. I am relatively new to Angular, so there is probably some elementary concept that I am missing.

Comment: Have you debugged the script to see what the value of `$scope.data.flips` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove min and max attributes, due to this validation does not allow to change the ng-model.

Alternative if  you want to maintain the min and max you can add ng-model-options like this:

```html
<input ng-change="checkLimit()" type="number" min="1" max="5000000" name="input" ng-model="data.flips" required
                           ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true, updateOn: 'blur' }"/>
```

Note that we are using ng-model-options, thus we have to use the appropriate angular version  >=1.4

Comment: JIC: It updates the data on blur event in the input. if you want it to update right away, remove the updateOn: 'blur' from the ng-model-options. But I guess it is user friendly with the onblur.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: see cccross' answer for a cleaner version

<s>You need to escape the current digest cycle, as I don't believe that angular will update an element with a new property value if the property value was updated in a change event from that element.</s>

There may be cleaner ways to do what you request; however, this example works. I removed the 'min' and 'max' input attributes, and moved your ng-change listener logic into a '$timeout' call. $timeout is included as a controller argument. $timeout will trigger another digest cycle, which will update your input.

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("controller", function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.checkLimit = function() {
        $timeout(() => {
            $scope.data.flips = $scope.data.flips > 5000000 ? 5000000 : 
            $scope.data.flips;
            $scope.data.flips = $scope.data.flips < 1 ? 1 : $scope.data.flips;
        })
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaxwaudv/3/)

Comment: See my answer for a cleaner solution

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct - your answer fails to update the value displayed in the input element. http://jsfiddle.net/xaxwaudv/4/

Comment: It works. It updates the data on blur event in the input. if you want it to update right away, remove the  updateOn: 'blur' from the ng-model-options. But I guess it is user friendly with the onblur.

Comment: I could have created a bad example, but I don't see what I *think* is your answer working at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xaxwaudv/5/

Comment: wrong fiddle link. here's the correct link: http://jsfiddle.net/xaxwaudv/5/

Comment: Your example is wrong man, It is missing the definition of the controller in the angular context app.controller('....... ')

Comment: It's a different controller, but it's using the same event listener

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle for your example?

Comment: One more thing my example,  only works for  angular version >= 1.4, Note tha we are using ng-model-options

Comment: Update the version did it. Thanks for clarifying. http://jsfiddle.net/xaxwaudv/6/